# Write after end error when using PythonShell in Node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I tried to run python script from my Node.js api using PythonShell module. It runs perfectly fine at the first time. But when I call the api again, Write after end error occurs. Here's part of my code.

the import part.

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var pyshell = new PythonShell('script.py');
```

the router part which calls python script.

```
router.get('/sendinfo', function(req, res,next) {

pyshell.send(JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,6]));

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
    // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)
    console.log(message);      
});

// end the input stream and allow the process to exit
pyshell.end(function (err) {
    if (err){
        throw err;
    };

    console.log('finished');
    res.json({ message: 'api finished' });  
    next();

    });
});
```

And this is a full text error

```
Error: write after end
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:167:12)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:214:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Socket.write (net.js:634:40)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at PythonShell.send (C:\Users\Chanon\Desktop\SIP\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:205:16)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.handle (C:\Users\Chanon\Desktop\SIP\server.js:35:10)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next_layer (C:\Users\Chanon\Desktop\SIP\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:113:13)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Chanon\Desktop\SIP\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:117:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\Chanon\Desktop\SIP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:222:24
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Users\Chanon\Desktop\SIP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:288:12)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\Chanon\Desktop\SIP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:216:19)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\Chanon\Desktop\SIP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:180:38)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle (C:\Users\Chanon\Desktop\SIP\server.js:26:2)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Chanon\Desktop\SIP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:263:17)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\Chanon\Desktop\SIP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:225:9
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Users\Chanon\Desktop\SIP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:288:12)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\Chanon\Desktop\SIP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:216:19)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found that:

```
pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
    // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)
    console.log(message);      
});
```

…will be triggered multiple times depends how many times you call the API.

My solution:

```
router.get('/sendinfo', function (req, res, next) {

    pyshell.send(JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3, 4, 6]));

    pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
        // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)
        console.log(message);
        res.result = {
            message: message
        };
        next();
    });

    // end the input stream and allow the process to exit
    pyshell.end(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.error = {
                error: err
            }
        };

        console.log('finished');
        res.result = {
            message: 'api finished'
        };
        next();

    });
}, function (req, res) {
    if (res.result) {
        res.status(200).json(res.result)
    } else {
        res.status(500).json(res.error)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by putting

```
var pyshell = new PythonShell('script.py');
```

into an api like this

```
router.get('/sendinfo', function(req, res,next) {

var pyshell = new PythonShell('script.py');

pyshell.send(JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,6]));

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {    
   console.log(message);      
});

pyshell.end(function (err) {
   if (err){
      throw err;
};

console.log('finished');
res.json({ message: 'api finished' });  
next();
   });
});
```